# Unexpected Output from Array (Not really getting output, the process freeze and doesn't end)

Tags: c, arrays

I am practicing arrays now and in this program I am trying to get prime numbers through this procedure called Sieve of Eratosthenes. But my program does not end. It keeps on running. I thought my netbeans might be broken or something but then it run other programs just fine.
My output is  an array from 1 to 100 and after that program keeps on running until I terminate it manually.
so please have a look and tell me what am I doing wrong here ?

Please click link below to see the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num[100], a, c, b;

    //initializing Array

    for(a = 0; a <= 99; a++)
    {
        num[a]=a+1;
    }
    printf("your array \n");
    for(a = 0; a <= 99; a++)
        printf(" %d",num[a]);

     //Applying Condition
     for(a = 1; a < 99; a++)
     { 
          if(num[a]==0)
              continue;
          else
              for(b = 2; b < 100; b++)
              { 
                  num[(num[a] * b) - 1] = 0;
              }
     }

     //New Array
     printf("\n new array\n");
     for(a = 0; a <= 99; a++)
     {
         if(num[a][enter image description here][1]!=0)
             printf("%d ",num[a]);
         else 
             continue;
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

here is the link to output I get. Array is in one line so cannot show all upto 100.

[image]

Comment: `num[(num[a] * b) - 1] = 0` can (will) vault out of the allowed range of you 100 element array. In  doing so, your program falls off the cliff into the great void of *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Use a debugger and see what causes your program to never stop.

Comment: to Assign multiples of a number to zero.

Comment: Thanks alot WhozCraig.. you always clear my concepts. best regards

Answer (score 1):

Your `b` loop is wrong. An alternative is :

```
for (b = 2 * num[a]-1; b < 100; b += num[a])
    num[b] = 0;
```

The math would have been a little less obtuse if you would have just used a 0-value in slot `num[0]`, but it is what it is. Your original code was easily breaching the declared size of your array by building a `num` index from the product of `b * num[a]`, which can work, but only for products below 100, which you weren't guarding against. The alternative above addresses that problem.

Changing that, your program produces the following output for the second number list:

```
1 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Comment: thanks alot..
and also when I got to know that i am unknowingly exceeding Array size this little math worked..

for(b=2 ; b<=100/num[a] ; b++)

Comment: @AustinSpark sure. As I said, several ways to do it. pick whatever works and is easiest to understand.